# Identifying groups of rows by value order

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to identify groups of rows by order of values in one column. Attached is some example data. I have a column "FID" which is ordered but the order is discontinuous. I need to create a new column that numbers each group of FID values.

To reiterate; if I have 2, 3, 11, 12, 13, I would need 2 & 3 to have a group number of 1 and 11, 12, & 13 to have a group number of 2.

Example of data and my desired column (Group) below.

Thank you for any help in advance!
Ryan

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB3dP.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to create a separate section that listed the groups and highest number in those groups, you could use the Lookup function. Say, like the data in your image, you have columns A through F populated with data. Let's say you have Column I and J for a lookup table. Column I could list the groups (1, 2, 3, and so on) column J could list the highest FID allowed in that group. (300, 500, 600, etc.). Then, in column F, where you currently have you groups, you could use the lookup formula.

`=LOOKUP(A2:A26,$J1$1:$J$6,$I$1:$I$6)`

You would, however, have to replace `$I$1:$I$6` and `$J$1:$J$6` with the correct ranges for your lookup table.

Comment: I'm probably asking for something that can't be done. There aren't more than 5 values in any one group (range) and the number of values between groups is pretty variable. If that weren't the case then I think your method would be a lot easier for this situation.

Comment: How do you determine what FIDs go into which groups? How many groups are we looking at total? We could look at a crazy ugly `IF` statement, or using `INDEX` and `MATCH` instead, depending.

Comment: We are talking upwards of 400 groups. I need consecutive numbers to go in a group with any breaks signaling the start of a new group. Groups numbers should be ordered by FID. So, if I have 3,4,5,12,13,15,16 I would need group #s 1(3,4,5), 2(12,13), and 3(15,16). Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do what you're asking without using a macro to create a lookup table for the groups (or using a macro to do all the work). Is using a macro a possibility?